# How to kill a celery task

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, django-views, djcelery

#### tasks.py

```
@task
def daterange():
    import datetime
    some = Poll.objects.all()
    schedule = Schedule.objects.all()
    for c in schedule :
        p = c.poll
        e = c.end_time
        s = c.start_time
        n = int(c.no_of_response)
        ph = Response.objects.filter(poll = p).exclude(sid = 'Null').count()
        now = timezone.now()
        if (c.start_time <= now) & (now <= c.end_time):
            if (n == 0) | (n > ph):
                c.poll.status='Running'
                c.poll.save()
            elif(n == ph):
                c.poll.status='Complete'
                c.poll.save()
                #time.sleep(1000)
            else:
                c.poll.status='Out of Bound'
                c.poll.save()
        elif c.end_time < now:
            c.poll.status='Complete'
            c.poll.save()
        elif c.start_time > now:
            c.poll.status='New'
            c.poll.save()
```

#### models.py

```
class Schedule(models.Model):
        poll = models.ForeignKey(Poll, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        start_time = models.DateTimeField() 
        end_time = models.DateTimeField() 
        no_of_response = models.IntegerField(default = 0)
```

I have scheduled a celery running task every 10 seconds.The periodic task including the code for updating the poll survey according to the start time and end time. If the poll is in between the start time and end time, then update the poll status into running.If currently the status is running then how to stop the poll when the end time is reached.How to kill a celery task in this project?

Comment: Please include some of the code here including the celery and your modal so we further debug your code...

Comment: models.py class Schedule(models.Model):
 poll = models.ForeignKey(Poll, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
 start_time = models.DateTimeField()
 end_time = models.DateTimeField()
 no_of_response = models.IntegerField(default = 0)

Answer (score 0):

Retry task until success execution. Example of possible implementation:

```
from celery import current_task

# decorator to retry task
def retry_if_false(func):
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
        if not func(*args, **kwargs):
           current_task.retry()
    return wrapped

 @retry_if_false
 @task
 def daterange():
     ..<your code>..
     return c.poll.status == 'Complete'  # return True if polling finished.
```

Now you can start your task as normal task no need to add it to celerybeat.

Comment: How the result can occur?

Comment: Do not understand question. Idea: You start task with decorator `@retry_if_false`, if you want to run it again - return `False` and it will be executed again, if not - return `True` and task will stop executing.

Comment: Celery does not kill task, it just stop executing it. You can add log date of tasks execution and check it. Actually you can just add `print` and look at celery worker output.

Comment: 'revoke(c.poll.task_id, terminate=True)' I use this code for killing the celery task in the poll complete section. There is no error in the code. But the task is not revoked. Why?